# Determine PickerView Value After IBAction is pressed

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

I have an iOS UiPicker working with my desired values and can detect when a new option is selected with the following code:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSString *aCompany = [arrayColour objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Picked:"
                          message:aCompany
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];


}
```

My question is how do I get the latest from the picker after pressing a button like this:

```
- (IBAction)DoneButton:(id)sender {



    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Picked:"
                          message:aCompany
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];

}
```

Comment: `IBAction` is not pressed. `IBAction` is a type (typedeffed to `void`). Buttons are pressed. And I'm de-pressed, because this has nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: I feel like I'm always up-voting your comments @H2CO3, but this is the first time one has made me laugh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up your `pickerView` as an `IBOutlet` (and link using IB) then you can access it outside of the `didSelectRow`.

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *myPickerView;
```

Then you can use the following line in `DoneButton`:

```
NSString *aCompany = [arrayColour objectAtIndex:[self.myPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
```